# Twilio REST Api call bad request

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I've implemented Twilio REST API with C# successfully earlier. However, all of a sudden the API calls that are made keep getting 400 - BAD REQUEST.

The response body doesn't contain any specific error either...

I'll say it again, it worked for a week or two and all of sudden it returns BAD REQUEST.

The code is exact the following below.

```
public async Task SendSmsAsync(string number, string message)
{
    var accountSid = _configuration["Authentication:Twilio:AccountSID"];
    var authToken = _configuration["Authentication:Twilio:AuthToken"];
    var twilioNumber = _configuration["Authentication:Twilio:Number"];

    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountSid, authToken);
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var url = $"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{ accountSid }/Messages";
            var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("To", number),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("From", twilioNumber),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Body", message),
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);
            content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Uri success = response.Headers.Location;
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that your `AuthToken` or `AccountSID` values are still valid? I'm not familiar with the Twilio API, but it seems like you may have expired some of your credentials.

Comment: I've tryed the request from their web console and it works... It uses the same values. However, if it was expired credentials I would have gotten Unauthorized as response insted of BAD REQUEST

Comment: Hmm. I would recommend loading up a Web Debugger such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and seeing what kind of HTTP headers, body content, etc the remote API endpoint expects.

Comment: So if you run `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync` does that come back as empty?